# shading certain area in graph - a combination of lines and point plots in base R

Tags: r, graph, radix

I have following question:

```
set.seed(1234)
dis = seq(1, 800, 10)
 yvar = rnorm(length (dis), 50, 10)
myd <- data.frame (xvar = dis, yvar = yvar, yvarL = 
yvar - rnorm (length (yvar),5, 1), yvarU = yvar + rnorm (length (yvar), 5, 1))
plot(myd$xvar,myd$yvar,pch=19,cex=.75,col="blue")
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvarL,col="gray", pch=19,cex=.5)
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvarU,col="gray", pch=19,cex=.5)
```

Y has three values - Y, upper and lower confidence. I would like to shade between two intervals in axis. Rest of graph would be point only. The hypothesized product graph should be similar (not exactly).

[image]

How can I shade and produce line plot between two intervals say between 650 to 690 and 210 to 280 in myd$xvar. I tried to do some polygot fitting based on this post ( [shading within xy curve plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449597/shading-within-xy-curve-plot-in-r)), but not successful.

```
polygon(c(myd$xvar[1:200], myd$xvar[200:1]), c(myd$xvar[1:200],
   myd$yvar[200:1]), col="gray")
```

Comment: You might need to subset your data and plot lines for some while points for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar answer to Stephan :

```
plot(myd$xvar,myd$yvar,pch=19,cex=.75,col="blue")
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvarL,col="gray", pch=19,cex=.5)
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvarU,col="gray", pch=19,cex=.5)
polygon(c(smyd$xvar[1:nrow(smyd)], smyd$xvar[nrow(smyd):1]), 
 c(smyd$yvarL[1:nrow(smyd)], smyd$yvarU[nrow(smyd):1]), col="gray", border = NA)
points(smyd$xvar,smyd$yvar,col="red", pch=19,cex=1.5)
lines (smyd$xvar,smyd$yvar,col="red", pch=19,cex=1.5)

polygon(c(smyd1$xvar[1:nrow(smyd1)], smyd1$xvar[nrow(smyd1):1]),
c(smyd1$yvarL[1:nrow(smyd1)], smyd1$yvarU[nrow(smyd1):1]), col="yellow", border = NA)
points(smyd1$xvar,smyd1$yvar,col="green4", pch=19,cex=1.5)
lines (smyd1$xvar,smyd1$yvar,col="green4", pch=19,cex=1.5)
```

gives you:
 [image]

Answer (score 4):

One problem with your data is that myd has only 80 observations, but you are trying to plot 200... Just feed the x variable twice into `polygon()` (once as-is, once in reverse order), then the y variable (first the lower limit as-is, then the upper limit in reverse order). Then you have your shading:

```
polygon(c(myd$xvar[20:40], myd$xvar[40:20]),c(myd$yvarL[20:40],
 myd$yvarU[40:20]), col="gray")
```

However, the shading will cover some points, so you will have to re-plot them:

```
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvar,pch=19,cex=.75,col="blue")
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvarL,col="gray", pch=19,cex=.5)
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvarU,col="gray", pch=19,cex=.5)
```

EDIT: rfan below asks to shade based on the x coordinate, not the index, and to add a line in the shaded region. For this, it makes sense to extract an index of the relevant points (we use that myd$xvar is sorted):

```
index <- which(myd$xvar>=200 & myd$xvar<=400)
```

We then plot based on this index, which we can easily modify if we need to:

```
polygon(c(myd$xvar[index], myd$xvar[rev(index)]),c(myd$yvarL[index], 
 myd$yvarU[rev(index)]), col="gray")
```

Now, add a line and the additional points:

```
lines(myd$xvar[index],myd$yvar[index],pch=19,cex=.75,col="blue",type="o")
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvarL,col="gray", pch=19,cex=.5)
points(myd$xvar,myd$yvarU,col="gray", pch=19,cex=.5)
```

Comment: thanks, how can I plot line for yvar in the shaded region only (please see model figure). Can we set margin with at 200 in xvar (not 20th value), in this way it would be much easier to shade certain region based on xvar value

Comment: @rfan: I edited the answer based on your question. Does this help?

Comment: yes, this certainly what I need... finding index is sometime difficult than X cutoff points